# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/star/lang/XEventListener

Tags: java, pdfbox, jodconverter

I am using [pdfbox](https://pdfbox.apache.org/)(pdfbox-app-2.0.0-RC3.jar) to convert `any` file to `.pdf` file. I am also using **jodconverter-2.2.1.jar**  library.

Code I wrote (following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16605211/add-ms-office-documents-to-pdf-via-apache-pdfbox)):

```
import com.artofsolving.jodconverter.openoffice.connection.*;
import com.artofsolving.jodconverter.openoffice.converter.*;
import com.artofsolving.jodconverter.*;
import java.io.File;
public class PdfBox {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    
    try {
        OpenOfficeConnection con=new SocketOpenOfficeConnection(8100);
        con.connect();
        File inputFile=new File("x.docx");
        File outputFile=new File("x.pdf");
        DocumentConverter converter=new OpenOfficeDocumentConverter(con);
        converter.convert(inputFile,outputFile);
        con.disconnect();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
} 
}
```

Error message I get:
[image]

Any idea to get rid of this will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add `openoffice-ridl-2.0.3.jar` (or some version of openoffice's jar) to your classpath.

Comment: I am unable to find that .jar download link  searching google. help me please?

Comment: How I can download http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/o/Downloadopenofficeridl203jar.htm this file?

Comment: You should be using some kind of dependency resolution mechanism like Maven. The maven repository has all the jars you'll need - but there's a lot more you'll need to include just to use jodconverter: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.artofsolving/jodconverter/2.2.1